# How to tail -f log file with python on browser

Tags: python, flask

I want to create a script with python flask or bottle module to print my `/var/log/messages` logs with `tail -f` command.

```
import subprocess
from bottle import route, response, run

@route("/")
def file():
    response.content_type = "text/plain"
    while True:
        return subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-4", "file"])

run(host='localhost', port=888)
```

when i try it with `tail -f` the page just hangs and loads for ever.

Comment: `tail -f` actually blocks current process. When you type it on terminal, it also blocks you, right?

Comment: the script run fine but on localhost:888/ the page loads forever with no output.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f\ actually block current thread, it never`return` until you terminate it.

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify or http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/ Would be a better idea.